# Manage multi-tenancy ArangoDB connection

Tags: go, arangodb

I use ArangoDB/Go (using go-driver) and need to implement multi-tenancy, means every customer is going to have his data in a separate DB.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to make this multi-tenancy work. I understand that it's not sustainable to create a new DB connection for each request, means I have to maintain a pool of connections (not a typical connection pool tho). Of course, I can't just assume that I can make limitless, there has to be a limit. However, the more I think about that the more I understand that I need some advice on it. I'm new to Go, coming from the PHP world, and obviously it's a completely different paradigm in PHP.

Some details
I have an API (written in Go) which talks to ArangoDb using arangodb/go-driver. A standard way of creating a DB connection is

- create a connection
  conn, err := graphHTTP.NewConnection(...)
- create client
  c, err := graphDriver.NewClient(...)
- create DB connection
  graphDB, err := p.cl.Database(...)

This works if one has only one DB, and DB connection is created on API's boot up.
In my case it's many, and, as previously suggested, I need to maintain a DB connections pool.

Where it gets fuzzy for me is how to maintain this pool, keep in mind that pool has to have a limit.
Say, my pool is of size 5, abd over time it's been filled up with the connections. A new request comes in, and it needs a connection to a DB which is not in the pool.
The way I see it, I have only 2 options:

1. Kill one of the pooled connections, if it's not used
2. Wait till #1 can be done, or throw an error if waiting time is too long.

The biggest unknow, and this is mainly because I've never done anything like this, for me is how to track whether connection is being used or not.
What makes thing even more complex is that DB connection has it's own pool, it's done on the transport level.

Any recommendations on how to approach this task?

Comment: If your question is about the scalability of multi-tenancy in ArangoDB, that has nothing to do with Go or PHP.

Comment: @Adrian, I'm asking to validate my idea of multi-tenant DB connection management. Also, it would be great to see some recommendations on how to do that, or how not to...

Comment: Which still has nothing to do with Go or PHP. As written, the question is so vague it's unanswerable. Yeah, you'll want to use some kind of connection pool; no, you can't open infinite connections. Hard to give any recommendation or say if you're "thinking in the right direction" since no real detail is given on what you're actually trying to accomplish or what direction you're thinking other than some kind of finite connection pool.

Comment: All right, I hear you @Adrian, let me try refine my explanation, and I'll update my original question once it makes sense to you.

Comment: @Adrian, does it make more sense now?

Comment: If you're using HTTP as a transport, you don't need to worry about any of it. HTTP connections are generally not long-lived, and Go handles keepalive and pooling internally. Each request to the database is a distinct unit that may or may not re-use an open HTTP connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162840/discussion-between-ivan-naumenko-and-adrian).

Answer (score 2):

I implemented this in a Java proof of concept SaaS application a few months ago.

My approach can be described in a high level as:

1. Create a Concurrent Queue to hold the Java Driver instances (Java driver has connection pooling build in)
2. Use subdomain to determine which SaaS client is being used (can use URL param but I don't like that approach)
3. Reference the correct Connection from Queue based on SaaS client or create a new one if not in the Queue.
4. Continue with request.

This was fairly trivial by naming each DB to match the subdomain, but a lookup from the _systemdb could also be used.

*Edit
The Concurrent Queue holds at most one Driver object per database and hence the size at most will match the number of databases. In my testing I did not manage the size of this Queue at all.

A good server should be able to hold hundreds of these or even thousands depending on memory, and a load balancing strategy can be used to split clients into different server clusters if scaling large enough. A worker thread could also be used to remove objects based on age but that might interfere with throughput.

Comment: @ivannaumenko the Queue has at most one object per database. The database connection pool is managed via driver https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/blob/master/README.md#connection-pooling

Comment: I understand that, you said "Create a Concurrent Queue to hold the Java Driver instances", right? where the Queue has at most one object per database like you also said. If you have hundreds of DB, are you going to keep all of them in the Queue, and it has no limit on the size?

if not, and Queue does have a size, you need to manage it. That's what I asked.

Comment: @IvanNaumenko hopefully my edit answers the question better. Ideally, the Queue has no size limit, but that depends on server resources of course.

Comment: it totally makes sense, and this is exactly the way I did my implementation.