# Multi-tenancy with a separate database per customer, using Spring Data ArangoDB

Tags: java, spring-data, arangodb

So far, the only way I know to set the name of a database, to use with Spring Data ArangoDB, is by hardcoding it in a `database()` method while extending `AbstractArangoConfiguration`, like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableArangoRepositories(basePackages = { "com.company.mypackage" })
public class MyConfiguration extends AbstractArangoConfiguration {

  @Override
  public ArangoDB.Builder arango() {
    return new ArangoDB.Builder();
  }

  @Override
  public String database() {
    // Name of the database to be used
    return "example-database";
  }

}
```

What if I'd like to implement multi-tenancy, where each tenant has data in a separate database and use e.g. a subdomain to determine which database name should be used?

Can the database used by Spring Data ArangoDB be determined at runtime, dynamically?

This question is related to the discussion here: [Manage multi-tenancy ArangoDB connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174019/manage-multi-tenancy-arangodb-connection)  - but is Spring Data ArangoDB specific.

Comment: Another option to implement multi-tenancy would be to add a tenant key to each document and all query predicates, but then the separation between each tenant is less "clean" and database-per-tenant seems to be the ArangoDB preferred approach:  "Different databases are usually used for multi tenant setups, as the data inside them (collections, documents etc.) is isolated from one another." - https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/data-modeling-concepts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is delightfully simple:  Just change the `ArangoConfiguration` `database()` method `@Override` to return a Spring Expression (SpEL):

```
    @Override
    public String database() {
        return "#{tenantProvider.getDatabaseName()}";
    }
```

which in this example references a `TenantProvider` `@Component` which can be implemented like so:

```
@Component
public class TenantProvider {

    private final ThreadLocal<String> databaseName;

    public TenantProvider() {
        super();
        databaseName = new ThreadLocal<>();
    }

    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return databaseName.get();
    }

    public void setDatabaseName(final String databaseName) {
        this.databaseName.set(databaseName);

    }
}
```

This component can then be `@Autowired` wherever in your code to set the database name, such as in a servlet filter, or in my case in an Apache Camel route Processor and in database service methods.

P.s. I became aware of this possibility by reading the [ArangoTemplate](https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/blob/master/src/main/java/com/arangodb/springframework/core/template/ArangoTemplate.java#L130) code and a [*Spring Expression support* documentation section](https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/blob/master/docs/Drivers/SpringData/Reference/Mapping/Document.md#spring-expression-support)
 ([via](https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/issues/145)), and [one merged pull request](https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/pull/103).