# How to use SPEL in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-el

As stated in [Multi-tenancy with a separate database per customer, using Spring Data ArangoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451843/3852459) I can retrieve customer related information via SPEL and use it in my database configuration.

But how do I do that when using Spring WebFlux?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly, what is the information you're trying to retrieve?

Comment: I want to retrieve my current session attribute, say `customerId` and inject to the `database` string

Comment: inject customerid to the database string? I'm not really sure why would you do that, or are those separate two goals? Could you add details to the question?

SPEL is not really about changing any values, only reading from them, if that's what you mean by injecting.

Comment: I want to add multi-tenancy to my ArangoDB, thus said, I want to be able to have separate databases for each customer, and upon a request, I need to find out the database url by customer id

Comment: @Carmine : Any updates ?