# Create Dynamic collections with ArangoDB using Spring JPA

Tags: database, spring-data-jpa, nosql, arangodb

I want to create Arango collection at runtime through my application apis using Spring JPA.

How can I create a collection on runtime based on the inputs from request for collection name?

I have tried SPEL but I am getting ILLEGAL Name error when I am trying with dynamic inputs from the request

Any help on this, I am stuck with this?

Comment: I am able to achieve this using SPEL by referring this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432395/multi-tenancy-with-a-separate-database-per-customer-using-spring-data-arangodb

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do it is via the HTTP API of Arango.

Look at these pages to get the general idea on how the requests need to be put together (it's pretty simple):

- https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/general.html
- https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/database.html
- https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/collection-creating.html#create-collection

Also, on the Web UI of your ArangoDB, click "Support" on the left sidebar, and then "REST API". There you can even try out the requests and get the exact URL, parameters, etc right before putting it in your code.